# How to display columns from MySQL in one row with counters for each items

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am pretty new to programming so pardon if my question sound silly. I am trying to list rows from MySQL database. My requirement is to have a counter for each items in a row for every designations under a department. 
Eg : I have each row with name of department and designations corresponding the department in MySQL DB. I have tried to demonstrate the structure of MyMSQL table below.The output I am trying to get is the following format

```
Department          Desig1              Desig2              Desig3
==========          ======              ======              ======
IT                  Director            Manager             Asst. Mgr
Finance             Finance Contr       Finance Mgr         Chartd Acct.
Admin               CEO                 Gen. Mgr.           Mgr
```

This is how the output I am looking forward for.

```
IT
1 Director
2 Manager
3 Asst. Manager

Finance
1 Finance Controller
2 Finance Manager
3 Charted Accountant

Administration
1 CEO
2 General Manager
3 Manager
```

I tried to retrieve data from MySQL using below code, couldn't get the result in the format I was looking for. Tried adding an increment within the same loop thinking it might help but I was wrong. Please advise.

Note : I am using bootstrap for the background design.

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "dbname";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) 
    {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "SELECT Dept, Desig1, Desig2, Desig3 FROM comdept";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
    {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
        {
            i=0;
            echo "<div class='panel-heading'><div class='panel-title'><strong>".$row["Dept"]."</strong></div></div><table class='table table-bordered table-hover'><thead><tr><th class='col-sm-1'>SL</th><th>Designations</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>".i++."</td><td>".$row["Desig1"]."</td></tr><tr><td>".i++."</td><td>".$row["Desig2"]."</td></tr><tr><td>".i++.".</td><td>".$row["Desig3"]."</td></tr></tbody></table>";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "0 results";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this format instead :

```
$i=0;
echo "<table class='table table-bordered table-hover'>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    echo "<tr><td colspan=2>".$row["Dept"]."</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>".$i++."</td><td>".$row["Desig1"]."</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>".$i++."</td><td>".$row["Desig2"]."</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>".$i++."</td><td>".$row["Desig3"]."</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td colspan=2></td></tr>";

}
echo "</table>";
```

Hopr this helps.

Comment: Thanks Zakaria Acharki for the suggestion but I may want to have the 1st column dynamically because not all Dept has values for Desig2 and Desig3. That's why i thought of having an increment.

Comment: Many thanks Zakaria Acharki. That actually fixed my problem with a small modification. But you gave me the spark. I added the $i=1 within the while loop so that it resets everytime the loop works.

Answer (score 0):

there is a error on you query "SELECT Dept, Desig1, Desig2, Desig3 FROM comdept" column heading is "Department" and not "Dept"
this is the corre
`

```
echo $sql = "SELECT Department, Desig1, Desig2, Desig3 FROM comdept";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table class='table table-bordered table-hover'>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        echo "<tr><td colspan=2>".$row["Department"]."</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>1</td><td>".$row["Desig1"]."</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>2</td><td>".$row["Desig2"]."</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>3</td><td>".$row["Desig3"]."</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td colspan=2></td></tr>";
        //$i=0;
    //echo "<div class='panel-heading'><div class='panel-title'><strong>".$row["Dept"]."</strong></div></div><table class='table table-bordered table-hover'><thead><tr><th class='col-sm-1'>SL</th><th>Designations</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>".i++."</td><td>".$row["Desig1"]."</td></tr><tr><td>".i++."</td><td>".$row["Desig2"]."</td></tr><tr><td>".i++.".</td><td>".$row["Desig3"]."</td></tr></tbody></table>";
    }echo "</table>"; else{echo "0 results";}
```

`

Comment: Sorry, please consider that as my typo. My intention of typing Department was  only for demonstration and  Dept is what I am actually using in my SQL query.